# Address Of String Literals in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I have read that the type of string literal is char[n+1], where n is the length.The storage of string literals is an implementation issue.But still it must be unique at an instant.

```
printf
("%u\t %s\t  %d\t  %c\t  %f\t  %e\t  %x\t  %p\t",
&"XY",&"XY",&"XY",&"XY",&"XY",&"XY",&"XY",&"XY");
```

The output of this code is

```
4206628 XY 4206628 $ 0.000000 1.800980e-307 7ffde000 00000032
```

Why `%f` gives zero, `%s` gives XY (no effect of `&`?), and `%p` gives a totally different value?

Comment: The type of string literals in C is `char [N + 1]` where `N` is the length of the string, not `const char [N + 1]`.

Comment: i read somewhere it was const...thx

Comment: this is the case in C++

Comment: And for your question, all your conversions invoke undefined behavior,  none is correct.

Comment: %x to print the pointer's address, %p for the same at least these two should be consistent.I used %u even to print addresses earlier , are all incorrect?

Comment: `x` and `u` require an `unsigned int` and `p` requires a `void *`. Use `printf("%p\n", (void *) "XY");` to print the address of the string.

Comment: thx.for other types of variables & can be used as it is, right?one doubt still, are memory addresses negative also cause I haven't come across them yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `%f` gives zero?

Because `%f` expects a `double` while it's not, this leads to undefined behavior.

> `%s` gives `XY` (no effect of `&`?)

Possibly because for an array `arr`: `arr` and `&arr` have the same value. However, the type is different, which means you are passing the unexpected type to `printf`, again, undefined behavior.

> and `%p` gives a totally different value?

That's the pointer value you are looking for.

Comment: %u should also give the address which is different from what %p gives.or are they expected to give different results?

Comment: @user2653718 Again, `%u` expects an unsigned integer, but it's not, so undefined behavior.

Comment: address can be -ve also?but still %x and %p should point to same address?the decimal equivalent of hexa is 2147344384 here, whereas % p gives other value.Is only %p the correct way to print the address?

Comment: @user2653718 each %-code has an expected type of a certain size (width in bits)... which means each code interprets the value you provide differently _with the potential to include examining fewer or greater bits than you have provided_.

Comment: fewer or greater bits than provided,i understood so no. of bits will make difference even if size of the types is same, understood.so unsigned int and signed int will also differ in that regard.okay.thanks.

Comment: `arr` and `&arr` not only have different types but may have different representations. The C standard does not require implementations to use the same representations for pointers of different types. Passing a pointer to an array of `char` when `printf` expects a pointer to `char` has behavior undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure, I didn't make myself clear on that, I'll fix it right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass values of the wrong type (a type that doesn't match what the formatting specifier says is expected) and not get undefined behavior.

For instance, it's quite possible that a `double` which is what `%f` expects is *bigger* than a pointer (which is what you're actually) passing, thus leading to a mis-match between the passed values and the values consumed by `printf()`, and more or less mayhem as a result.

Comment: also &"XY" which is a pointer gives XY via %s. Why?At least some no. like hexadecimal  should have had got printed?

Comment: %f understood.similar reason for %c but %p and %u should give the same result, right?

Comment: okay..thx. not using % u %x is the correct option.i suppose for all types.

Comment: @user2653718: No.  Pointers and `unsigned int` may not be the same size, and may not be passed to functions in the same way.